# ffmpeg 1 image (JPG) + 1 audio file (MP3) = 1 video (WEBM) using real encode (-re)

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, streaming

I'd like to make video streaming to distribute it in a streaming.
The mp3 file is being extracted from a video file (which is being recorded live) and, while audio being extracted (MP3), I want to take this audio file and a image it and spread it in a real time streaming. But `-re` is not working for this.

To extract audio file i use:

```
ffmpeg.exe -re -i file(LIVE).AVI -vn -ar 22050 -ab 16k -r 1 -ac 1 -f mp3 C:\Users\" & wshNetwork.Username & "\Documents\audio.mp3"
```

This work very well to make the MP3 file. Using `-re`.

After that, I'm using this command to marge the auvio file with the jpg image:

```
ffmpeg.exe -loop 1 -f image2 -i c:\picture.jpg -re -i c:\Users\" & wshNetwork.Username & "\Documents\audio.mp3 -vb 10k -ar 22050 -ab 16k -ac 1 -r 1 -bufsize 300k -f webm www.adress.com
```

This second command is not working because the `-re` is not working, and produce a video with the picture and a choppy audio.

the output is:

```
ffmpeg version N-63113-g72dcd48 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on May 12 2014 22:10:08 with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetyp
e --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --ena
ble-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-l
ibopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsp
eex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aa
cenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavp
ack --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable
-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 83.100 / 52. 83.100
  libavcodec     55. 61.100 / 55. 61.100
  libavformat    55. 37.102 / 55. 37.102
  libavdevice    55. 13.101 / 55. 13.101
  libavfilter     4.  5.100 /  4.  5.100
  libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
  libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, image2, from 'c:\imagens\radiobb.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc), 553x342 [SAR 96:96 DAR 553:342], 25
 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[mp3 @ 0000000002b8f660] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurat
e
Input #1, mp3, from 'C:\Users\f3548956\Documents\audio.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf55.37.102
  Duration: 00:00:09.34, start: 0.050113, bitrate: 16 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: mp3, 22050 Hz, mono, s16p, 16 kb/s
[swscaler @ 0000000002ae1640] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did se
t range correctly
[libvpx @ 0000000002a8da40] v1.3.0
Output #0, webm, to 'http://172.17.146.***:8080/publish/tvbb100?password=****'
:
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf55.37.102
    Stream #0:0: Video: vp8 (libvpx), yuv420p, 553x342 [SAR 1:1 DAR 553:342], q=
-1--1, 10 kb/s, 1k tbn, 25 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: vorbis (libvorbis), 22050 Hz, mono, fltp, 16 kb/s
Stream mapping:
    Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg -> libvpx)
    Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (mp3 -> libvorbis)
    Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
    frame=   33 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=     4kB time=00:00:01.32 bitrate=  23.3kbits/s
    frame=   67 fps= 66 q=0.0 size=     4kB time=00:00:02.68 bitrate=  11.5kbits/s
    frame=  101 fps= 66 q=0.0 size=    11kB time=00:00:04.04 bitrate=  22.4kbits/s
    frame=  133 fps= 66 q=0.0 size=    11kB time=00:00:05.32 bitrate=  17.0kbits/s
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Please include the full, uncut command line output.

Comment: ffmpeg.exe -loop 1 -f image2 -i c:\picture.jpg -re -i c:\Users\" & wshNetwork.Username & "\Documents\audio.mp3 -vb 10k -ar 22050 -ab 16k -ac 1 -r 1 -bufsize 300k -f webm 172.17.146.***:8080/publish/tvbb?password=*******

Comment: That's the command line, but we need the *output*, that is, everyting starting from `ffmpeg version ...` until the last line. Please [edit] it into the question. Also make sure to use code formatting (the `{}` button in the editor).